# Jquery not working on html loaded from php via ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

**Description :**

I have an ADMIN PANEL in which admin can change the views on his/her dashboard. like if he/she wanted to change the current password , would click on change password tab and all the UI (HTML,CSS every thing related) would be loaded from php like below

```
<?php

echo '<div class = "change_pass_header"></div>'

//so on and so forth

?>
```

Now I have written the jquery when admin clicks the update password button it should call 
`$.post()` and post all the values to a certain php page like this

```
$("body").on("click","#update_pass",function(){

$.post("pass_send_to_php.php",{pass:pass},function(response){

alert(response);    
});

});
```

and yes it doesn't work when the div with id update_pass is loaded from the php via ajax

I am getting all the html from php like this

```
$("body").on("click","#change_admin_pass_b",function(){

    $.get("change_admin_password.php",function(ch_ad_pas){

        $(".main_admin_panel_body").html(ch_ad_pas);

    });


});
```

But if the any div with same id is pre written on that page and is not being loaded from any php then any jquery function e.g click works as it should ..

Why is this happening ?? Anyone?

Comment: I know that! with the same ID meant if any of the two divs have this id one being on the same page or one loaded from a php ... both behave differently...

Comment: oohh Why aren't you getting it ... I said it as an example.. I said if the same div with that id is pre written on page then it works and if I "Remove that div from HTML" and put it on the php page to be loaded it doesn't work.. Get it??